# JUnit test No ParameterResolver registered for parameter in constructor

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit-5

Quiero hacer una prueba con Junit a un metodo de mi clase RegistrationService la prueba lo que debe hacer es enviar una nueva "request" para registrar un usuario
Esta es la prueba

@AllArgsConstructor
class RegistrationDemoApplicationTests {

```
private  final RegistrationService registrationService;

@Test
void itShouldRegister() {
    
RegistrationRequest request = new RegistrationRequest("marlo", "stanfield", "marlo@gmail.com", "clave");

registrationService.register(request);
    
}
```

}

La clase Registration request es esta

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class RegistrationRequest {
    
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final String email;
    private final String password;

}
```

y el metodo que registraria al usuario es este

```
public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());

        if (!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Email is not valid");
        }

        String token = appUserService.signUpUser(
                new AppUser(
                        request.getFirstName(),
                        request.getLastName(),
                        request.getEmail(),
                        request.getPassword(),
                        AppUserRole.USER
                        )
                );

        
        return token;
    }
```

Lo que quiero hacer es enviar una nueva request para ver si se registra el usuario pero me da un error asi > No parameterResolver registered for parameter

Comment: Yo se que el metodo .register() funsiona porque cuando lo pruebo   con postman si registra el usuario pero la prueba no funsiona

Answer (score 0):

Si está utilizando Lombok, puede indicarle a Lombok que anote el constructor generado como se muestra en este [blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok).

Le sugiero agregar esta anotación:
***@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)***

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor_ = @Autowired)
class RegistrationDemoApplicationTests {
private  final RegistrationService registrationService;
@Test
void itShouldRegister() {
    
RegistrationRequest request = new RegistrationRequest("marlo", "stanfield", "marlo@gmail.com", "clave");

registrationService.register(request);
    
}
```